# Finding a result set in a range where my condition is also a range

Tags: mysql

I have a query string containing a range, say x and y. I need to get values from database those values that includes x and y, searching in the field where values are also a range, min and max.

The values are:

1. x and y is inside the min and max
2. min greater than x but less than y and
3. max is greater than x but less than y

Comment: Can you show some *actual* examples of your schema, data, conditions and expected output? Your abstract description isn't going to get you much help

Answer (score 0):

Your examples 2 and 3 are the following

```
SELECT * FROM table
   WHERE min BETWEEN x AND y 
      AND max BETWEEN x AND y
```

Example 1 is the opposite

```
SELECT * FROM table
   WHERE x BETWEEN min AND max 
      AND y BETWEEN min AND max
```